# Product shortdescription is invisible

Tags: html, css, controller, smarty, prestashop

im using a shopsoftware called "prestashop" and got a little problem. If you are logged in as a customer you can choose to add products a a favorite. We use images in our product short descirptions and by default the facorite products get displayed with there short description. Due to the fact that we use pictures we just get "&nbsp'" instead of the pictures.

This is in the controller of the favoriteproduct-> front office -> account:

```
class FavoriteproductsAccountModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
public $ssl = true;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    require_once($this->module->getLocalPath().'FavoriteProduct.php');
}

public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();

    if (!Context::getContext()->customer->isLogged())
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication&redirect=module&module=favoriteproducts&action=account');

    if (Context::getContext()->customer->id)
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign('favoriteProducts', FavoriteProduct::getFavoriteProducts((int)Context::getContext()->customer->id, (int)Context::getContext()->language->id));
        $this->setTemplate('favoriteproducts-account.tpl');
    }
}
}
```

And this is the .tpl:

```
{capture name=path}
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
        {l s='My account' mod='favoriteproducts'}
    </a>
    <span class="navigation-pipe">{$navigationPipe}</span>
    <span class="navigation_page">{l s='My favorite products' mod='favoriteproducts'}</span>
{/capture}

<div id="favoriteproducts_block_account">
    <h1 class="page-heading">{l s='My favorite products' mod='favoriteproducts'}</h1>
    {if $favoriteProducts}
        <ul class="row">
            {foreach from=$favoriteProducts item=favoriteProduct}
            <li class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="favoriteproduct clearfix inner-content">
                    <a 
                    class="product_img_link"
                    href="{$link->getProductLink($favoriteProduct.id_product, null, null, null, null, $favoriteProduct.id_shop)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                        <img 
                        src="{$link->getImageLink($favoriteProduct.link_rewrite, $favoriteProduct.image, 'medium_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" 
                        alt=""/>
                    </a>
                    <p class="s_title_block">
                        <a href="{$link->getProductLink($favoriteProduct.id_product, null, null, null, null, $favoriteProduct.id_shop)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                            {$favoriteProduct.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <div class="product_desc">{$favoriteProduct.description_short|strip_tags|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</div>
                    <div class="remove">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return false" rel="ajax_id_favoriteproduct_{$favoriteProduct.id_product}">
                            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {else}
        <p class="alert alert-warning">{l s='No favorite products have been determined just yet. ' mod='favoriteproducts'}</p>
    {/if}

    <ul class="footer_links clearfix">
        <li>
            <a 
            class="btn btn-default button button-small" 
            href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                <span>
                    <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>{l s='Back to your account' mod='favoriteproducts'}
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So .. if anyone could tell me what i have to delete i would be very thankfull.

Comment: Actually i can see the short description as .html now after removing the "|stripe_Tags", any suggestions how to enable html?

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
{$favoriteProduct.description_short|strip_tags|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

into

```
{$favoriteProduct.description_short}
```

However you need to be sure that code is safe otherwise someone can at least break your layout